# Google Query Trim string data

Tags: regex, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-query-language

I am using the following data:

```
cat1-001A
cat1-001B
cat1-001C
dog2-001A
etc.
```

the query I used is

```
=query(sheet1!A1:A,"select A where A is like '%cat%'",1)
```

Using this query pulls data as cat 1-3. Is there a way within the query to trim the text to only return the word cat? I do not want the -1, -2, -3.

so the value returned will be cat.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use `COUNTIFS()` then. For example `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("cat|",COUNTIF(A:A,"*cat*")),"|"))`?

Comment: how can you use this within a query

Comment: Why `QUERY()`? It's an alternative rather. Usually faster than any regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

not within query. use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(Sheet1!A1:A, 
 "select A where A contains 'cat'", 1), "-\d+$", ))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(Sheet1!A1:A, 
 "select A where lower(A) contains 'cat'", 1), "-\d+.+", ))
```

[image]

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(Sheet1!A1:A, 
 "select A where lower(A) contains 'cat'", 1), "\d+-\d+.+", ))
```

[image]

Comment: @Tkr17 answer updated

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
=REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(Sheet1!A1:A, 
 "select A where A contains 'cat'", 1), "\d-\d+.*",)
```

[image]